# Can't play wmv files

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, codecs, wmv

64 bit Ubuntu can not play wmv files. How can I fix it? I installed w64codecs but it didn't work. 
Thanks.

Comment: From my experience, the wXXcodecs work with mplayer but not vlc for certain formats like wmv3, give gnome mplayer a shot.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on the actual codec of the wmv file. I mainly use VLC and it can play most wmv files i have came upon.

HOWEVER - a DRM 'protected' WMV file - is not playable in anything other then windows media player from my experience.

You can get some info about the .wmv in question by right clicking on it, and selecting properties. Also most media players have menu items to give detailed infomation about the codecs used on a loaded file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give SMPlayer a chance,I'm not sure if it helps but try `sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code solved the issue for me in 2020, for Ubuntu 20

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvd-pkg gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```